# How do I parallelize this lapply() function in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, r-future

I am trying to perform a grid search to find coefficients that maximize the correlation between a linear combination of x's and y. My function takes a data.frame where each column is the thetas to test for that iteration.

```
corr_grid_search <- function(thetas, modeling_df) {

    # thetas = as.vector(thetas)
    coeff1 = modeling_df$penalty1 / thetas[1]
    coeff2 = modeling_df$penalty2 / thetas[2]
    coeff3 = modeling_df$penalty3 / thetas[3]
    coeff4 = modeling_df$penalty4 / thetas[4]
    coeff5 = modeling_df$penalty5 / thetas[5]
    coeff6 = modeling_df$penalty6 / thetas[6]
    coeff7 = modeling_df$penalty7 / thetas[7]
    coeff8 = modeling_df$penalty8 / thetas[8]
    coeff9 = modeling_df$penalty9 / thetas[9]
    coeff10 = modeling_df$penalty10 / thetas[10]

    df = data.frame(coeff1, coeff2, coeff3, coeff4, coeff5, coeff6, coeff7, coeff8, coeff9, coeff10)

    pp_1 = modeling_df$x1 / df$coeff1
    pp_2 = modeling_df$x2 / df$coeff2
    pp_3 = modeling_df$x3 / df$coeff3
    pp_4 = modeling_df$x4 / df$coeff4
    pp_5 = modeling_df$x5 / df$coeff5
    pp_6 = modeling_df$x6 / df$coeff6
    pp_7 = modeling_df$x7 / df$coeff7
    pp_8 = modeling_df$x8 / df$coeff8
    pp_9 = modeling_df$x9 / df$coeff9
    pp_10 = modeling_df$x10 / df$coeff10

    recip = 1/df[, c('coeff1', 'coeff2', 'coeff3', 
    'coeff4', 'coeff5', 'coeff6', 
    'coeff7', 'coeff8', 'coeff9', 'coeff10')]
    recip = as.data.frame(lapply(recip, function(x) replace(x, is.infinite(x), NA)))

    df = data.frame(pp_1, pp_2, pp_3, pp_4, pp_5, pp_6, pp_7, 
        pp_8, pp_9, pp_10)

    weighted_x = rowSums(df, na.rm=T) / 
        rowSums(recip, na.rm=T)

    cor(weighted_x[!is.na(weighted_x)], 
           modeling_df[!is.na(weighted_x),]$y)
}
```

I have it running with lapply() like so:

```
lapply(blah, corr_grid_search, modeling_df)
```

But am trying to parallelize it and having trouble. The two methods I have tried use the parallel and future.apply libraries, but neither has worked:

```
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)
cors = future_lapply(blah, corr_grid_search, modeling_df)
```

```
library(parallel)
cl = makeCluster(32)
clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist=c("modeling_df"))
cors = parLapply(cl, blah, corr_grid_search, modeling_df)
```

Something is going wrong with both of them because they take horrendously long, 2-3 orders of magnitude slower. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @SamR, That is a good observation, thank you. There are a lot of unneeded columns in the dataframe for this task, I will try subsetting only the columns I need.

Comment: @SamR, Thank you, that was the problem. I thought that because my function only read from the dataframe it would not need to copy back and forth. 75x increase after passing only the columns the function needs. If you make an answer I will accept it if you care about that haha

Comment: Wanted to run some simulations for myself so I posted an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Parallel processing is not always faster than a single thread

There are two frequent situations in my experience where parallel processing ends up slower than using a single-thread:

1. The data is large and copying it between workers is expensive.
2. The task allocated to each worker is fast enough that the overhead of setting up workers impacts significantly.

### 1. Copying data between workers can cost more time than parallel processing saves

As the `furrr` [docs](https://furrr.futureverse.org/) note:

> It’s important to remember that data has to be passed back and forth between the workers. This means that whatever performance gain you might have gotten from your parallelization can be crushed by moving large amounts of data around. For example, if you are moving large data frames to the workers, running models in parallel, and returning large model objects back, the shuffling of data can take a large chunk of that time.

### A quick simulation

We can see an example of this if we define an inefficient function. This function calculates the mean of a data frame column, but then instead of returning this single value, creates a new data frame column with the value recycled. It then returns the **entire** data frame with this new column appended:

```r
silly_fun <- function(dat, col_name) {
    mean_col_name <- paste0(col_name, "_mean")
    dat[[mean_col_name]] <- mean(dat[[col_name]])

    return(dat)
}
```

It would be a bad idea to run this function over every column of a data frame, whether in parallel or not.

So, let's try it with only 100 rows and columns and see what happens:

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)

nrows <- 100
ncols <- 100
dat <- data.frame(
    matrix(rnorm(nrows * ncols), nrows, ncols)
)

res <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    single_thread = lapply(names(dat), \(col_name) silly_fun(dat, col_name)),
    parallel = future_lapply(names(dat), \(col_name) silly_fun(dat, col_name)),
    times = 100
)
```

Output:

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 single_thread   2.9771   3.26725   3.876938   3.43705   3.91215   9.6273   100  a 
      parallel 103.5295 114.23415 126.105709 123.41755 132.39925 235.1055   100   b
```

As you can see, the median for the parallel job is about 35 times that of the single-threaded.

If we try it with 1000 rows and columns, these are the results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
 single_thread   168.5477   168.5477   168.5477   168.5477   168.5477   168.5477     1
      parallel 29440.3962 29440.3962 29440.3962 29440.3962 29440.3962 29440.3962     1
```

Here it takes **175 times** as long to run in parallel. You can see that I've only done one iteration here - a single-threaded iteration took 0.168 seconds but doing it in parallel took 29.4 seconds!

### 2. The overhead of setting up workers can be more expensive than the time saved

Let's take a more sensible example and just return the actual mean, rather than the entire data frame, with 1000 rows and columns. You might think that now we're not passing large amounts of data, parallel processing will be much quicker. Let's see:

```r
nrows <- 1e3
ncols <- 1e3

dat <- data.frame(
    matrix(rnorm(nrows * ncols), nrows, ncols)
)
sensible <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    single_thread = lapply(dat, mean),
    parallel = future_lapply(dat, mean),
    times = 10
)

Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 single_thread   4.3159   4.65055   5.245647   4.88995   5.37955  10.3636   100  a 
      parallel 157.9709 163.17605 177.565840 169.55155 180.03720 513.5421   100   b
```

Both methods perform a lot better in absolute time (both cases with 1000 rows and columns look like their respective timings with 100 rows and columns using the silly method).

But it's still *much* faster to use a single thread, because of the high overhead of setting up the workers compared with the relatively quick operation of calculating a mean.

Overall the fact that a parallel job may not be quicker does not indicate that the code is not creating the sub-processes as intended. There are costs and benefits of parallel processing. It is *a lot* faster in the right situations, but if you're copying large datasets or creating processes to do very simple calculations, it can be slower than a single-threaded approach.