# Is there any simple task that allows me to understand whether my embarassingly parallel program works fine?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

I am employing an embarassingly parallel routine using `mclapply()` of the `parallel` package in *R* in order to simulate independent paths of a stochastic process.
I am surprised that I could not get any speed gain over the non-parallel program, though.

Is there any task which is established to be performed faster in parallel than on a single core which I can use to check whether the system is working as expected?

Comment: The answer already posted is good. See also [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706306/how-do-i-parallelize-this-lapply-function-in-r/74709053#74709053) for some examples where parallel processing is not faster than a single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try executing

```
Sys.sleep(5)
```

which suspends the session for 5 seconds. If the parallelisation works, then each of the worker processes should be sleeping at the same time.

---

```r
library(parallel)
library(tictoc)

f <- function(...) {
  Sys.sleep(1) 
  "DONE"
}

tic()
res <- lapply(1:5, f)
toc()
#> 5.025 sec elapsed

tic()
res <- mclapply(1:5, f, mc.cores = 5)
toc()
#> 1.019 sec elapsed
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>