# When is furrr::future_pmap() faster than pmap()?

Tags: r, future, doparallel

I implemented a function that is quite expansive.

```
start<-Sys.time()
plan(multicore, workers = 4)
grid <- expand.grid(v,x,y,z)
mapping<-pmap(list(grid[,1],grid[,2],grid[,3],grid[,4]),.f=function(v,x,y,z){
  ...
},.progress=TRUE)
plan(sequential)
end <- Sys.time()
end-start
```

this is faster than the same with `future_pmap()`

Then I tried to do a simpler function because I read that big dataframes or list that get passed around by the workers makes it slow.

```
start<-Sys.time()
plan(multicore, workers = 4)
future_pmap(list(grid[,1],grid[,2],grid[,3],grid[,4]),.f=function(v,x,y,z){
  return(sum(v,x,y,z))
})
plan(sequential)
end <- Sys.time()
end-start
```

I tried different dimensions of `grid` and the last was

```
10901000        4
```

never was `future_pmap()`  faster, rather slower. So did I implement it incorrectly or what can I do?

Comment: ah Ok with 'multisession' instead of 'multicore' it is actually a lot faster. I wonder how to use multicore then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parallelize this lapply() function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706306/how-do-i-parallelize-this-lapply-function-in-r)

Comment: Windows?  Available strategies depend on a system; `multicore` is not supported on Windows - https://future.futureverse.org/reference/plan.html#built-in-evaluation-strategies-1